# Wordpress loop not looping over posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress theme and for some reason even though I have posts it is showing that I do not have any posts.

```
<?php if(have_posts()){ ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) { ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>


        <?php while ( have_posts() ){ the_post();  ?>

            <?php
            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format()); ?>


        <?php } ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php }else{ ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
   <?php } ?>
```

I'm having issues with debugging it since it shows their are posts.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it seems like you made a mistake in templates paths, they should be "template-parts/post/content" - you lost "post/" directory.

Comment: all of them are in the same folder called template-parts

Comment: but this code is in template outside 'template-parts' directory? and directly inside this directory you have content.php file?